# Vivado Libraries

Tags: vhdl, libraries, vivado

I am trying creating a library of components that I can use in Vivado(2014.2). I have many .vhd files and I would like to add more in the future, and so I'd prefer not to have to condense them
all into a single .vhd.

I may need to use a package...
ie.

```
--File name: my_library_file
package my_lib_package is 
--All component declarations...
end package my_lib_package;
```

But would all the entities and architectures also need to be in this file?

Then I could use a "use" statement to reference these elements.
ie. use my_lib.
But would the my_library_file need to be located in the same project?

I would like to be able to make this library once and be able to reference in
any project with a call.

Ideally it could be called like an IEEE library but with many vhd files being referenced.

I would prefer not to explicitly add/include these individual source files to the project, but would instead prefer to just be able to use the “use” clause with library and/or package…if possible.

Comment: Are our answers at EE.SE not good enough? If so, extend your question or write comments.

Comment: I still haven't been able to fix my problem. If I have a package built I don't see how I could set it up to work like this in Vivado, 

library my_library;
use my_Library.package.all;

Active-HDL allows you to attach libraries in their library manager and then the components are available. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in Vivado.

Answer (score 0):

Hayden - your approach to making your own package of components sounds fine. We use the same approach with a single package file of "comps". It is written as a package and has the component instance as well as the entity and architecture of each component. Look at any of the Xilinx or Altera library source files as a guide.

You can compile it into it's own library and call it just like you do with the Xilinx libraries in Vivado.